# Core Data: Parent context and change propagation

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following Core Data setup in my app:

```
Persistent Store Coordinator
  ^ Background MOC (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
      ^ Main Queue MOC (NSMainQueueConcurrencyType)
```

Here is the initialization code:

```
_backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_backgroundContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.coordinator];
_mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[_mainContext setParentContext:_backgroundContext];
```

I use the background MOC for importing large amounts of data. I also use it to perform complex fetch requests in the background and then pass the object IDs to the main queue to fetch the objects using these IDs.

This works quite well. However, I am not sure how to let the main queue MOC know about the changes made in the background MOC. I know that if I perform a fetch request on the main queue MOC, it will get the changes, but that's not what I want.

Is it OK to use the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` notification posted by the background MOC and call `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on the main queue MOC? This should then cause the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` notification of the main queue MOC to fire. I am listening for this notification in my view controllers and examine the `userInfo` for changes and redisplay data accordingly.
I think you usually do it this way if you have one persistent store coordinator with two attached MOCs. But I am not sure if it is the right way to do, when you have child/parent contexts.

Answer (score 6):

Having the main MOC use a private parent MOC for asynchronous I/O is fine.  However, you should not use that parent MOC for anything but performing background work on behalf of the main MOC.  There are many reasons for this (among them performance and nasty issues related to transient object IDs).

If you want to do background updating of the store, here is what I suggest.

```
PSC <--+-- PrivateMOC <---- MainMOC
       |
       +-- BackgroundPrivateMOC
```

This will allow background operation that causes the least interruption to the main MOC, while allowing the PSC caches to be shared.

Now, for sharing data...

The MainMOC should listen for and merge DidSave notifications from the BackgroundPrivateMO.

The BackgroundMOC can listen for and merge DidSave notifications from the PrivateMOC.

This allows merging to use only permanent object IDs and optimizes performance.

Comment: Is it possible to make BGPrivateMOC as a child of mainMOC and propagate all BG changes by saving BGPrivateMOC? I've tried to do so, but my mainMOC didn't get any changes from the BGPrivateMOC. Decided to to try your stack. It works like a charm.

Comment: Oh, something went wrong, it does not work anymore. The merge does not update main context.

Comment: You need to provide more details than that... maybe enter a new question with details about your specific problem... and maybe comment here about that question if you want me to see it...

Comment: Yep, I'm gonna give you a link to my question as soon as I prepare the sample code

Comment: Hi, pls check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520133/threaded-core-data-merging-to-unsaved-context

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that listening to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` notification is not probably the best solution.

The way I do it and it works is following.
Here is main context creation:

```
_mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
_mainContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
_mainContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Here is background context creation:

```
_backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
_backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
_backgroundContext.parentContext = self.mainContext;
```

Now, background context is only for writing (or reading) objects (may be in background thread). Main context is only for reading from the main queue.
Save on background context should look like:

```
__block BOOL saved = [_backgroundContext save:error];
if (saved && _backgroundContext.parentContext) {
    [_backgroundContext.parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        saved = [self.parentContext save:error];
    }];
}
```

This save method guarantees that all changes will be propagated to main context. If you do  a lot of work in many background threads get more familiar with `performBlockAndWait:` method, which provides mutual exclusion on context.

If you want to be notified about objects' changes, you don't have to listen for notification, you can simply setup `NSFetchedResultsController` and register as its delegate.