# Multicontext Core Data: merging to unsaved context

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to implement this core data stack:

```
PSC <--+-- MainMOC
       |
       +-- BackgroundPrivateMOC
```

There are some things I'm actually don't understand. Perhaps we have an object in our Persisten Store and we fetch it from the main MOC to do some changes (user change it manually). At the same time my BG MOC is doing some changes with the same one object and save the changes to PS. After the saving is done we must merge the BG MOC to the MAIN MOC (this is a common practice). What I expect after the merging is that the MAIN MOC contains changes from the BG MOC (because the changes were done a bit later than the MAIN ones). But this actually doesn't happened. All I have after the merging is finished is a dirty `refreshedObjects = 1` in my MAIN MOC and if I fetch that object again through the MAIN MOC, I don't see any changes made through the BG MOC.

- How should I correctly propagate BG changes to MAIN MOC while the
  MAIN MOC was not saved prior the BG changes was made?
- How to handle
  the situation when my MAIN MOC has non-zero `refreshedObjects` after merging is completed, and
  how to push these objects in the MAIN MOC to make them available to
  fetch and with?

I believe my sample code can help you to understand my problem more clearly. You can just download the project (https://www.dropbox.com/s/1qr50zto5j4hj40/ThreadedCoreData.zip?dl=0) and run XCTest, that I prepared.

Here is the failing test code:

```
@implementation ThrdCoreData_Tests

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

/**
 OUR SIMPLE STACK:

    PSC <--+-- MainMOC
           |
           +-- BackgroundPrivateMOC

 */
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    // main context (Main queue)
    _mainMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_mainMOC setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    [_mainMOC setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

    // background context (Private Queue)
    _bgMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    _bgMOC.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(mergeBGChangesToMain:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                               object:_bgMOC];

    u_int32_t value = arc4random_uniform(3000000000); // simply generate new random values for the test
    _mainMOCVlaue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u" , value];
    _expectedBGValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u" , value/2];

    Earthquake * mainEq = [Earthquake MR_findFirstInContext:self.mainMOC];
    if (!mainEq){  // At the very first time the test is running, create one single test oject.
        Earthquake * mainEq = [Earthquake MR_createEntityInContext:self.mainMOC];
        mainEq.location = nil; // initial value will be nil
        [self.mainMOC MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
    }
}

- (void)testThatBGMOCSuccessfullyMergesWithMain
{
    _expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"test finished"];

    // lets change our single object in main MOC. I expect that the value will be later overwritten by `_expectedBGValue`
    Earthquake * mainEq = [Earthquake MR_findFirstInContext:self.mainMOC];
    NSLog(@"\nCurrently stored value:\n%@\nNew main value:\n%@", mainEq.location, _mainMOCVlaue);
    mainEq.location = _mainMOCVlaue; // the test will succeed if this line commented

    // now change that object in BG MOC by setting `_expectedBGValue`
    [_bgMOC performBlockAndWait:^{
        Earthquake * bgEq = [Earthquake MR_findFirstInContext:_bgMOC];
        bgEq.location = _expectedBGValue;
        NSLog(@"\nNew expected value set:\n%@", _expectedBGValue);
        [_bgMOC MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait]; // this will trigger the `mergeBGChangesToMain` method
    }];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:3 handler:nil];
}

- (void)mergeBGChangesToMain:(NSNotification *)notification {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.mainMOC mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

        // now after merge done, lets find our object with expected value `_expectedBGValue`:
        Earthquake * expectedEQ = [Earthquake MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"location" withValue:_expectedBGValue inContext:self.mainMOC];
        if (!expectedEQ){
            Earthquake * eqFirst = [Earthquake MR_findFirstInContext:self.mainMOC];
            NSLog(@"\nCurrent main MOC value is:\n%@\nexptected:\n%@", eqFirst.location, _expectedBGValue);
        }
        XCTAssert(expectedEQ != nil, @"Expected value not found");
        [_expectation fulfill];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, when posting core data code, I suggest you not post code that depends on a third party library, unless that third party library is directly related to your problem.  I assume MR is magical record, but I don't use it, and it seems to just muddy the waters of the post because who knows what it is (or is not) doing under the covers.

In other words, try to trim examples down to as little as code as necessary... and no more... and only include third-party libraries when absolutely necessary.

Secondly, when writing unit tests for your core data usage, I suggest using an in-memory stack.  You always start empty and it can be initialized however you want.  Much easier to use for testing.

That said, your problem is a misunderstanding of what `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` does (and does not do).

Basically, you have an object in a Core Data persistent store.  You have two different MOCs attached to the store via the same PSC.

Your test then loads the object into main MOC, and changes the value without saving to the PSC.  A second MOC then loads the same object, and changes its value to something different (i.e., the store, and both MOCs all have a different value for a particular attribute of the same object).

Now, when we save the MOC, if there are conflicts, the conflicts will be handled as instructed by the `mergePolicy`.  However, the merge policy does not apply to `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`.

You can think of `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` as inserting any new objects, deleting any deleted objects, and "refreshing" any updated objects while preserving any local changes.

In your test, if you add another attribute (e.g., "title") and change both "title" and "location" in the BG MOC but only change "location" in the main MOC, you will see that the "title" gets merged from the BG MOC into the main MOC as expected.

However, as you note in your question, the "location" appears to not get merged.  In actuality, it does get merged, but any local change will override what's in the store... and this is exactly what you want to happen because the user likely made that change, and does not want it to be changed behind their back.

Basically, any pending local changes will override changes from the to-be-merged-MOC.

If you want something different, you have to implement that behavior when you do the merge, like this...

```
- (void)mergeBGChangesToMain:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSMutableSet *updatedObjectIDs = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSManagedObject *obj in [note.userInfo objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey]) {
        [updatedObjectIDs addObject:[obj objectID]];
    }

    [_mainMOC performBlock:^{
        for (NSManagedObject *obj in [_mainMOC updatedObjects]) {
            if ([updatedObjectIDs containsObject:obj.objectID]) {
                [_mainMOC refreshObject:obj mergeChanges:NO];
            }
        }

        [_mainMOC mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
    }];
}
```

That code first collects the `ObjectID`s of each object that was updated in the merged-from-MOC.

Prior to doing the merge, we then look at each of the updated objects in the merge-to-MOC.  If we are merging an object into our MOC, and our merge-to-MOC has also changed that object, then we want to allow the values in the merged-from-MOC to override those in the merged-to-MOC.  Thus, we refresh the local object from the store, basically discarding any local changes (there are side effects, e.g., causing the object to become a fault, releasing references to any relationships, and releasing any transient properties - see documentation of refreshObject:mergeChanges:).

Consider the following category, which addresses your situation, and a common problem when using observers like `NSFetchedResultsController`.

```
@interface NSManagedObjectContext (WJHMerging)
- (void)mergeChangesIntoContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
    withDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
    faultUpdatedObjects:(BOOL)faultUpdatedObjects
    overrideLocalChanges:(BOOL)overrideLocalChanges
    completion:(void(^)())completionBlock;
@end

@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (WJHMerging)
- (void)mergeChangesIntoContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
    withDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
    faultUpdatedObjects:(BOOL)faultUpdatedObjects
    overrideLocalChanges:(BOOL)overrideLocalChanges
    completion:(void (^)())completionBlock {
    NSAssert(self == notification.object, @"Not called with");

    NSSet *updatedObjects = notification.userInfo[NSUpdatedObjectsKey];
    NSMutableSet *updatedObjectIDs = nil;
    if (overrideLocalChanges || faultUpdatedObjects) {
        updatedObjectIDs = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:updatedObjects.count];
        for (NSManagedObject *obj in updatedObjects) {
            [updatedObjectIDs addObject:[obj objectID]];
        }
    }

    [moc performBlock:^{
        if (overrideLocalChanges) {
            for (NSManagedObject *obj in [moc updatedObjects]) {
                if ([updatedObjectIDs containsObject:obj.objectID]) {
                    [moc refreshObject:obj mergeChanges:NO];
                }
            }
        }

        if (faultUpdatedObjects) {
            for (NSManagedObjectID *objectID in updatedObjectIDs) {
                [[moc objectWithID:objectID] willAccessValueForKey:nil];
            }
        }

        [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

        if (completionBlock) {
            completionBlock();
        }
    }];
}
@end
```

Comment: are you sure there is not mistake here `if (faultUpdatedObjects) {`. I think it should be `if (!faultUpdatedObjects) {` instead.

Comment: Otherwise we should change the name of the parameter to `fireFaultedUpdatedObjects`. Isn't?

Comment: No to the first comment.  Your name is probably better than mine, but not quite right either because most of the time, in this situation, those objects are not even faults in the merge-to-MOC because they failed the fetch predicate.  After being updated in the other MOC they now fulfill the predicate, but there is no way to know that since they don't even exist.  You name suggests that they were faults in the merge-to-MOC.  My name suggests I'm faulting them in.  It's doing both.  Naming is hard: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html

Comment: Am I getting this right that after you sent `willAccessValueForKey` to the objects, they will become `fired faults` (`faults that are fired`)? In other words the property `isFault` will be `NO`?

Comment: Quote from the documentation for `willAccessValueForKey:`  "You can invoke this method with the key value of nil to ensure that a fault has been fired, as illustrated by the following example."